# sort data from csv to txt

Tags: c#, csv, text-files, console-application

I am writing a application which sorts out data from a csv to txt.

I have witten but I cannot get the required output.

Can someone please help, I do not see were I went wrong.

I initially thought its the File.WriteAllLines which was the problem but even when I write to a console I get the same results.

My file looks something like this

> Georgina,Sinclair,408999703657,cheque,First National Bank,Fourways,275.00,12/01/2012
>   Zachary,Whitehead,409122372301,cheque,ABSA,Irene,70.25,12/01/2012
>   Toby,Henderson,401255489873,cheque,First National Bank,Edenvale,181.03,12/13/2012
>   Katherine,Cooke,409155874935,savings,ABSA,Southdowns,975.89,01/01/2013
>   Bradley,James,409254998,savings,ABSA,Melville,207.74,12/09/2012
>   Sophie,Lane,409771987,savings,ABSA,Roodepoort,207.74,12/31/2012

My output should be something like this

```
First National B0020000045603
GSinclair       408999703657  CH Fourways  002750001122012
THenderson      401255489873  CH Edenvale  001810313122012
ABSA            0040000146162
ZWhitehead      409122372301  CH Irene     000702501122012
KCooke          409155874935  SAVSouthdowns009758901012013
BJames             409254998  SAVMelville  002077409122012
SLane              409771987  SAVRoodepoort002077431122012
```

The code I currently have only returns the header and 2 lines which looks as follows.

```
ABSA                    0040000146162
KCooke  409155874935    SAVSouthdowns   009758901012013
```

Please assist.

My code looks as follows

```
    string text = @"C:\\Test\\output.txt";
    var inputEntries = File.ReadLines(@"C:\\Test\\debitorders.csv").Select(line =>
    {
        var values = line.Split(',');
        return new
        {
            accountholder = values[0].Trim().Substring(0, 1) + values[1].Trim(),
            accountnumber = long.Parse(values[2].Trim()),
            accounttype = values[3].Trim(),
            bankname = values[4].Trim(),
            branch = values[5].Trim(),
            amount = 100 * double.Parse(values[6].Trim()),
            date = DateTime.Parse(values[7].Trim())
        };
    });
    var banks = inputEntries
                           .OrderBy(e => e.bankname)
                           .GroupBy(e => e.bankname, e => e);

    foreach (var bank in banks)
    {


        var AccountName = bank.Key;
        if (AccountName.Length >= 20)
        {
            AccountName = AccountName.Substring(0, 16);
        }
        else
        {
            AccountName += new string(' ', 20 - AccountName.Length);
        }
        var NumberOfAccounts = bank.Count();
        var TotalAmount = bank.Select(acc => acc.amount).Sum();
        var Header = AccountName + "\t" + NumberOfAccounts.ToString("000") + TotalAmount.ToString("0000000000");


        var sortedAccounts = bank
                                .OrderBy(acc => acc.accountholder)
                                .OrderByDescending(acc => acc.amount);


        foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
        {
            var outputLine =
            account.accountholder + "\t" +
            account.accountnumber + "\t" +

            //get first 2 characters
            account.accounttype.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + account.branch + "\t" + "00" +
            account.amount +
            account.date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(text, Header + Environment.NewLine + outputLine);

                Console.WriteLine(Header + outputLine);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get writing on console?

Comment: @M.Schena I have just editted my question, what I meant was I only get an output of two lines instead of all the lines

Comment: your code gives me formatexceptions

Comment: @M.Schena it works on my side with no issues what so ever

Comment: i changed the DateTime.Parse to: `date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[7].Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` this now works for me. I have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better and cleaner solution will be to make use of `List<string>` to which you add your text. At the end of the code just convert the list to an array and write all lines to a file.

```
List<string> outputLine = new List<string>(); //note this addition to the code

foreach (var bank in banks)
{

    //do header formatting stuff here
    var Header = somecode

    outputLine.Add(Header); //Add Header to outputLine

    var sortedAccounts = bank.OrderBy(acc => acc.accountholder)
                             .OrderByDescending(acc => acc.amount);

    foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
    {
        var tempStringBuilder =
        account.accountholder + "\t" +
        account.accountnumber + "\t" +
        //get first 2 characters
        account.accounttype.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + account.branch + "\t" + "00" +
        account.amount +
        account.date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

        outputLine.Add(tempStringBuilder); //Add tempStringBuilder to outputLine
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines("destination path", outputLine.ToArray()); //Write everything to your output file in one go
```

---

**Alternative Excel solution:**

Microsoft Excel has a really powerful tool called `Pivot Tables`, which is ideally suited to your needs. If you are unfamiliar with it, read some tutorials about it. At first it's a process to get your head around the workflow to use it but it is quite simple once you've grasped it. You just drag and drop fields by which you want to group.

You might also want to consider using `Data Connections` to link to your original data, which is also quite simple given the dataset you have.

Comment: Sweet, works like a charm, LINQ is not my strongest technique. need to have a look at it more often

Comment: I'm glad I could help. To write data to an array or list before writing the file also adds bit of a performance benefit since you don't need to access the file to write it each and every loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution:

```
File.AppendAllText(text, Header + Environment.NewLine + outputLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Use File.AppendAllText instead of File.WriteAllText. With WriteAllText you always deleted the old content.
But consider to clean the file (`File.WriteAllText(text, "");`) before you begin to write on it, otherwise you will have the old data from last run also in it.

Try to use `String.Format("{0,-10}", name)` which means that the length of the name is filled up with spaces up to the length of 10. Minus means left alignment and positive causes right alignment.

I updated your code to:

```
string text = @"D:\C#\output.txt";
File.WriteAllText(text, "");
var inputEntries = File.ReadLines(@"D:\c#\debitorders.csv").Select(line =>
{
    var values = line.Split(',');
    return new
    {
        accountholder = values[0].Trim().Substring(0, 1) + values[1].Trim(),
        accountnumber = long.Parse(values[2].Trim()),
        accounttype = values[3].Trim(),
        bankname = values[4].Trim(),
        branch = values[5].Trim(),
        amount = 100 * double.Parse(values[6].Trim()),
        date = DateTime.ParseExact(values[7].Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    };
});
var banks = inputEntries.OrderBy(e => e.bankname)
                        .GroupBy(e => e.bankname, e => e);

foreach (var bank in banks)
{
    var AccountName = bank.Key;
    var NumberOfAccounts = bank.Count();
    var TotalAmount = bank.Select(acc => acc.amount).Sum();
    var Header = String.Format("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2}", AccountName, NumberOfAccounts.ToString("000"), TotalAmount.ToString("0000000000"));

    var sortedAccounts = bank.OrderBy(acc => acc.accountholder)
                             .OrderByDescending(acc => acc.amount);

    File.AppendAllText(text, Header + Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(Header);
    foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
    {
        var outputLine = String.Format("{0,-11} {1,15} {2,-3} {3,-10} {4,7} {5,-10}",
            account.accountholder,
            account.accountnumber,
            account.accounttype.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper(),
            account.branch,
            account.amount,
            account.date.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
        );

        //get first 2 characters
        //account.accounttype.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + account.branch + "\t" + "00" +
        // what are the "00" for? didn't include them you may this do by yourself
        File.AppendAllText(text, outputLine + Environment.NewLine);

        Console.WriteLine(outputLine);
    }
    File.AppendAllText(text, Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output is:

```
ABSA                 004        0000146162
KCooke         409155874935 SAV Southdowns   97589 01012013  
BJames            409254998 SAV Melville     20774 09122012  
SLane             409771987 SAV Roodepoort   20774 31122012  
ZWhitehead     409122372301 CHE Irene         7025 01122012  

First National Bank  002        0000045603
GSinclair      408999703657 CHE Fourways     27500 01122012  
THenderson     401255489873 CHE Edenvale     18103 13122012
```

Comment: looks like its writing some records to the console but I still only get the 2 lines as an output to the textfile

Comment: sweet, its writing lines now but the format is totally wrong. only the first two lines are correct and everything else is duplicating

Comment: ok so this isn't wanted? why then there is a for loop 15 times? :D

Comment: I removed that part but still duplicates everything

Comment: Did you put File.WriteAllText(text, ""); at the beginning of your code?

Comment: Looks like the File.WriteAllText(text, ""); at the beginning solved the duplication part. Now I will just have to find a way to sort every thing to include the bankname as a header for every batch

Comment: do it like this: `File.AppendAllText(text, Header + Environment.NewLine + outputLine + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: its working but not as required. Have used Charl Pretorius solution and every thing seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: I will try and modify my original solution and let you know what was missing

Comment: yes would be a good idea. and show us please also how it exactly should look like

Comment: have a look at my post, i changed it. It may help you :)